# Change the name of created minified file in maven

Tags: maven, minify

I created a minified file with default name `1.js`.

How can I change the name of `1.js` to `snapshot.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you did not specify which plugin you are using for minification, assuming that you used `maven-minify-plugin` you will have to add `<jsFinalFile>` tag with your custom name:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-minify-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.5</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>min-js</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <jsSourceDir>path/to/js/dir</jsSourceDir>
            <jsSourceFiles>
                <jsSourceFile>1.js</jsSourceFile>
            </jsSourceFiles>
            <jsFinalFile>snapshot.js</jsFinalFile>
            <jsTargetDir>path/to/final/location</jsTargetDir>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>minify</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Thanks tmarwen I wrote a plugin similar you sent But I have one more problem! my 1.js file is in following path :${project.build.directory}/min/classes and when I write this path it gives me java.util.NoSuchElementException: The path [D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\src\main\webapp\D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\target\min\classes\1.js] cannot be found.error how can I change path?

Comment: Remove the **${project.build.directory}** so that the relative path path look like *min/classes*

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException: The path [D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\src\main\webapp\min\classes\1.js] cannot be found. There is a defult path like D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\src\main\webapp.when you add a path like min/classes it complete  like above path.I have to exit from webapp first of all

Comment: no I cant solve I couldnt change the defult path D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\src\main\webapp

Comment: I want to change path wit the folloving because 1.js created in this path D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\target\min\classes.When I write this path in <jsSourceDir>path/to/js/dir</jsSourceDir> it gives me this error:D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\src\main\webapp\D:\Users‌​\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\target\min\classes\1.js cannot be found.

Comment: Also I used <webappSourceDir> but again it gave me error.The path is correct and 1.js is in target\fcs-jsl-1.0-SNAPSHOT\js\1.js but it gives this error :java.util.NoSuchElementException: The path [D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\target\fcs-jsl-1.0-SNAPSHOT\js\1.js] cannot be found.

Comment: Do not put your js files under **target** directory. They should be under **src/main/webapp**. Move the whole directory */min/classes* under the later path and put your js files in there. The the <jsSourceDir> attribute should look like `<jsSourceDir>min/classes</jsSourceDir>`

Comment: Last question is how can I select all js file one time.because I have a lot of js in webapp now.When I write one by one it is ok but it is very long and bad choise.When I write like <jsSourceFile>*.js</jsSourceFile> it is not working.How can I select all js and put on the jsFinalFile with one jssourcefile?

Comment: Sorry but haven't run into this case previously as I mention all my input files one by one and never felt the need to add all with generic way like asterisc.

Comment: Sorry I have really last question :) Now I move js to under the webapp folder and Now I have two js folder and when I want to delete main/js it gives me this error:basedir D:\Users\otutan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fcs\fcs-api\src\main\js does not exist.I think we should change our basdir but I couldnt change.